# What brick is this? 1x2 with holes in the short sides

Tags: part-identification

This is my first time doing something like this, so here goes.  This is a 1x2 blue brick with holes on each end.  Through a hole, you get this view of the center peg and the light coming in through the other hole (pic 3).  From the bottom there is the peg, the holes on the sides, and the "Pend" from "Pat Pend" (pic 4). The "Pat" is above, but unable to be seen.

[image]

Finally, I have done a lot of research and found a grand total of nothing about it.  So, I tried some stuff out and learned that the only thing that fits in the holes are minifigure arms and thus speculated about a 4 arm guy.

[image]

Here are my tries at fitting other stuff.

[image]

Thanks for looking and sorry for so many pics!
-Erich Wacker

Comment: +1 for imagination with 4-armed guy!

Answer (score 10):

This is part [3317](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3317).

[image: 3317]

It's primarily used to hold the bucket on front end loaders. It hasn't been used in a set since the late 90's. [Part 3314](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3314) is about the only other part that is designed to connect to it that I'm aware of:

[image: 3314]

Here's an example of this part in use from set 6504:

[image]

While I believe that this was the only way to connect to this part used in official sets, I'm sure it may have other uses. It was used to build gas pumps in [one set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5TyY.jpg):

[image]

Comment: Oh the memories! I had that front-end loader :)